# Copy range of cells within VBA module

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to copy a range of cells in a specific sheet on the  click of a form button

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Sheets("Marina").Range("A1:H10").Value = Sheets("Marina").Range("A13:H22")
End Sub
```

In the VB editor I am using Module 1. That is where the code above lives.

[image]

I know that referencing sheets inside modules is different than inside scripts for the Workbook I have to use a Module. How would I go about referencing a specific sheet to execute the copy action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do actually move the code to a sheet *(Ex: Sheet1)*
2. After that is done you may delete the module
3. After that, go to your form object and `Right Click>Assign Macro...`
4. In the macro window, you should see all your functions under
   `sheet.[name of function]`
5. Now all the actions that need to be bound to a workbook should now execute without error